# The use of definite article before plural nouns

Tags: plural-forms

Is the use of THE justified in this sentence ? "The farmers are going to begin their agitation tomorrow.".

Comment: Does the word  'farmers' here refer to any specific use?. If not , Why the definite article was used here?{ the quote is from a reputed newspaper]

Comment: Presumably it refers to _the farmers_ of a particular country or region, or those taking part in a particular protest movement.

Comment: What do you think? Why would it not be justified?

Comment: Yes. I thought the word " farmers" being general it was not possible to put  'THE' before it.Now it is clear. Thanks